# Duvida Lista duplamente encadeada com inserção ordenada

Tags: c

Criei tudo porém o minha função de deletar está apagando o registro porém mantendo no print o código 0.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar meu erro? Também gostaria de saber se o meu algorítimo foi desenvolvido de maneira correta, sabendo que era para ser desenvolvido com lista duplamente encadeada com inserção ordenada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na função `exclusao`.Você está excluindo o registro mas não está diminuindo o tamanho da lista, já que a função `print` está usando a variável `lista->tamanho` como parâmetro de parada do loop `for`, a saída acaba sendo lixo de memória.É só colocar no final da função `exclusao` `lista->tamanho--` que resolve esse problema.
Aliás parece que você está usando uma lista cíclica, se você colocar `NULL` nos ponteiros pode dar falha de segmentação.
Com as correções:

```c
void exclusao(Lista* lista, int codigo)
{
    int achei = 0;
    Item* aux;
    Item* item = lista->primeiro;
    aux = item;
    while (aux && !achei)
    {
        if (aux->codigo == codigo)
        {
            if (aux == lista->primeiro)
            {
                if (aux == lista->ultimo)
                    lista->primeiro = lista->ultimo; //CASO 1
                else
                {
                    lista->primeiro = lista->primeiro->proximo; //CASO 2
                    lista->primeiro->anterior = lista->ultimo;
                }
            }
            else if (aux == lista->ultimo)
            { //CASO 3
                lista->ultimo = lista->ultimo->anterior;
                lista->ultimo->proximo = lista->primeiro;
            }
            else
            {//CASO 4
                aux->anterior->proximo = aux->proximo;
                aux->proximo->anterior = aux->anterior;
            }
            achei = 1;
            free(aux);
        }
        else aux = aux->proximo;
    }
    if (!achei)
        printf("\nCodigo inexistente!\n");
    else
        printf("\nExclusao realizada!\n");
   lista->tamanho--;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado!